# How to manipulate date type list to not capture time

Tags: apex, list

I'm trying to capture the smallest element of a list of type date, get the closest date in summary. Follow my code so far:

```
 public List<Quote> getOrcamentos(){
        if(lstOrcamentos == null) {
            lstOrcamentos = [
                SELECT Id, Name, Seguradora__r.Name, Retorno_da_Seguradora__c, Incluir_na_Proposta__c, 
                CotacaoEscolhida__c, ExpirationDate 
                FROM Quote
                WHERE OpportunityId =: oppId 
                ORDER BY CotacaoEscolhida__c DESC, Incluir_na_Proposta__c DESC, Seguradora__r.Name ASC 
            ];
        }
        
        //Populating the "dlistExpirationDates" list with budget expiration dates

        dlistExpirationDates=new List<Date>();
        for(Quote i:lstOrcamentos){
            dlistExpirationDates.add(i.ExpirationDate);
        }

        dlistExpirationDates.sort();//method that sorts the values of the list
        System.debug('dlistExpirationDates'+dlistExpirationDates);
        
        return lstOrcamentos;
    }
```

so far so good, the problem is that in the debug I'm getting the following: `|DEBUG|dlistExpirationDates(2022-05-30 00:00:00, 2022-05-31 00:00:00)`
I want to get only the day/month/year and not the time, does anyone know how I can do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's just how Date values are printed to the debug log. You can see it yourself:

```
System.debug(Date.today());
// Outputs: USER_DEBUG [1]|DEBUG|2022-05-10 00:00:00
```

They are proper dates, it's just that the `System.debug` method treats `Date` and `DateTime` variables in the same way. If you use a different method, like `Date.format()`, you'll see just the date.

All `Date` values are actually "secretly" `DateTime` values:

```
DateTime d = Date.today();
```

You can also see this by an assertion:

```
Date d = Date.today();
System.assert((Object)d instanceOf DateTime); // This passes!
```

Note that you can't, however, directly assign a `DateTime` to a `Date`, but instead must use the `date()` method:

```
Date d = DateTime.now().date();
```